# What word or phrase means 'that which provides a sense of meaning to one's life'?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

As in, "driving is my passion and my *x*".

I've been doing my head in looking for some sort of term which denotes such a thing, and I'm also concerned using the term "passion" might render the term I'm looking for a bit redundant (although it's clearly not defined as such, one's passion generally provides a sense of meaning or purpose, no?).

Comment: Why not, as you suggest, *purpose*?

Comment: One's ***calling***, or ***true calling***.

Answer (score 9):

The nearest thing to what you're looking for is a French term - *raison d'être* - meaning, "reason for existing", or the thing that gives meaning to your life. It's commonly used in English prose.

Answer (score 4):

I think that **meaning**, **calling**, or **purpose** can all be used and would work in the context.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be what you're thinking of but don't forget that "life" can be used in that context.

```
But music was his life, it was not his livelihood,
and it made him feel so happy and it made him feel so good.
And he sang from his heart and he sang from his soul.    
He did not know how well he sang; It just made him whole.
```

[Mr, Tanner by Harry Chapin](http://www.sing365.com/music/lyric.nsf/Mr-Tanner-lyrics-Harry-Chapin/4B1D6127C3391C4948256CAA002D7726)

Answer (score 0):

**Vocation** would work.

Although it is most often used in religious contexts, it isn't always.

Answer (score 0):

Many of us here outpassion with a [furor loquendi](http://useful_english.enacademic.com/441684/furor_loquendi) and a [furor scribendi](http://en.academic.ru/dic.nsf/mwc/74073/furor)